# Seaborn distplot only return one column when try to plot each Pandas column by loop for

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have problem when try to plot Pandas columns using for each loop
when i use `displot` instead `distplot` it act well, besides it only show distribution globally, not based from its group. Let say i have list of column name called `columns` and Pandas' dataframe `n`, which has column name `class`. The goal is to show Distribution Plot based on column for each class:

```
for w in columns:
    if w!=<discarded column> or w!=<discarded column>:
        sns.displot(n[w],kde=True
```

but when I use distplot, it returns only first column:

```
for w in columns:
    if w!=<discarded column> or w!=<discarded column>:
        sns.distplot(n[w],kde=True
```

I'm still new using Seaborn, since i never use any visualization and rely on numerical analysis like p-value and correlation. Any help are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably getting only the figure corresponding to the last loop.
So you have to explicitly ask for showing the picture in each loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for w in columns:
    if w not in discarded_columns:
        sns.distplot(n[w], kde=True)
        plt.show()
```

or you can make `subplots`:

```
# Keep only target-columns
target_columns = list(filter(lambda x: x not in discarded_columns, columns))

# Plot with subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(target_columns)) # see the parameters, like: nrows, ncols ... figsize=(16,12)
for i,w in enumerate(target_columns):
    sns.distplot(n[w], kde=True, ax=axes[i])
```